# Instantiate an additional window with monomac/c#

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, mono, monomac

I've been searching all over for the answer to this question, and while I realize it's likely very trivial, somehow the answer eludes me.

I need to show a second window (launched from clicking a menu item, if that matters). I know perfectly well how to do this with winforms, but I'm not sure what the monomac/NSWindow equivalent is. I need to do this:

```
MyWindowClass myWindow = new MyWindowClass();
myWindow.Show();
```

The best info I can find on the subject says that the following should work:

```
MyWindowClass myWindow = new MyWindowClass();
myWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

But when I try that, it tells me that MyWindowClass() needs an overload, so I look at the constructor and see that it's asking for an IntPtr.  Not knowing any better, I try this:

```
MyWindowClass myWindow = new MyWindowClass(new IntPtr());
myWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

This code will run without error, yet nothing happens when I try to launch the window.

I'm sure I'm just making a silly mistake, but I just haven't been able to find anything on the subject. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: For reference, here's the relevant portion of the constructor:

```
public MyWindowClass (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }
```

Additional info: I'm trying to run the code above from within AppDelegate.cs in the following method:

```
partial void showWindow (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject sender){
        MyWindowClass myWindow = new MyWindowClass(new IntPtr());
        myWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
    }
```

EVEN MORE CODE AHOY:

```
public partial class ViewPaths : MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindow
{
    #region Constructors
    public ViewPaths ()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    // Called when created from unmanaged code
    public ViewPaths (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    // Called when created directly from a XIB file
    [Export ("initWithCoder:")]
    public ViewPaths (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    // Shared initialization code
    void Initialize ()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then the actual instantiation:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
{
    MainWindowController mainWindowController;
    ViewPaths display;
    public AppDelegate ()
    {
    }

    public override void FinishedLaunching (NSObject notification)
    {
        mainWindowController = new MainWindowController ();
        mainWindowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);
    }


    partial void viewPaths (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject sender){
        display = new ViewPaths();
        display.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
    }

}
```

}

This shows a window with no UI elements of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a default constructor without the handle parameter.  Make sure MyWindowClass subclasses NSWindow and it should work.

Also, you may need to keep a reference to your myWindow around - so that it does not get garbage collected.

Comment: That's all I needed to do. Thank you! Didn't realize I could add an additional constructor outside of the one added for me by monomac.

Comment: Actually, this isn't working quite as intended -  it's showing a window, but not my window.

Edited original comment to show the class.

Comment: Found the problem. I was creating an instance of the window instead of the windowController. All better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, here's the final code that solved the problem, should anyone else ever google this:

Since I had created a new monomac window with a controller, I needed to create an instance of that controller, and show the controller's window:

```
MyWindowController myWindow = new MyWindowController();
myWindow.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

This did not need a new constructor without a handle parameter implemented - that solution was working around the problem I'd created by instantiating the incorrect thing.